# Use nested C loops to produce the following out put

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, data-structures, nested-loops

Am a beginner in C and I came across this question, How to produce the following pattern using C nested loops

```
BBBBBBB
BBBBBB
BBBBB
BBBB
BBB
BB
```

Code

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int Row, Col;
    for(Row = 7; Row >= -13; Row--)
    {
        for(Col = 1; Col <= Row; Col++)
       {
            printf("B");
        
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Row = 7; Row >= -13`? That makes no sense.

Comment: The code works *and I would say by chance*. It prints the desired output but the first loop goes on until `Row` is -13, so you print a bunch of new lines. What kind of help do you need? However, the logic behind is correct, using the first loop variable as the bound for the inner loop is the correct idea.

Comment: What is the correct and efficent way to produce the partern

Comment: Since you have 6 rows, common sense would suggest looping from 0 to i<6.

Answer (score 4):

The odd integer constants in the OP code don't make a lot of sense (even if they might work.)

One variable counting up while another counts down can be a bit like Zero Mostel's "One long staircase just going up, and one even longer coming down.." Hard to envision.

Try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for( int r = 1; r < 7; r++ ) { // output 6 rows
        for( int b = r; b <= 7; b++ ) // 1=>7, then 2=>7, then 3=>7... easy!
            putchar( 'B' ); // no need to engage all of printf() for a character
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
BBBBBBB
BBBBBB
BBBBB
BBBB
BBB
BB
```

In essence, one can imagine that the *floor* (the starting point) gets progressively higher, but the *ceiling* does not move.

---

Noticed that you ask, in the comments below your question, "What is the correct, efficient way...? "
Here is one way that does not use nested loops:

```
int main() {
    char *bees = "BBBBBBB";

    for( int i = 0; bees[i+1]; i++ ) // "+1" because pattern ends with "BB"
        puts( bees + i );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first one does not compile

Comment: @0___________ Thanks for that... Gotta stop "improving" variable names in the SO edit box... Thanks again `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier if you use functions and can test it with different numbers.

```
void printPattern(unsigned nrows)
{
    for(unsigned row = nrows; row > 0; row--)
    {
        for(unsigned col = 0; col <= row; col++)
            printf("B");
    printf("\n");
    }
}


int main()
{
    printPattern(7);
    printf("---------------------\n");
    printPattern(3);
    printf("---------------------\n");
    printPattern(1);
    printf("---------------------\n");
    printPattern(0);
    printf("---------------------\n");
    printPattern(15);
    printf("---------------------\n");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xjzMPczPE

Comment: Any comment silent DV-ter